# Point Pattern Analysis: L-r function

Tags: spatial, point-process

I'm new to pattern analysis. And I got a result of L-r function as below. So, how should I interpret the plot? Does it mean the points are cluster when L-r value is less than 0 and dispersed when the value is greater than 0?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/122816/919 for examples and interpretations of this function.

Answer (score 1):

and welcome to the site.

Actually the interpretation is just opposite of what you write. Values above zero indicate clustering and values below zero indicate regularity/dispersion/repulsion. However, the L-function is cumulative over all distances up to r and this makes the interpretation more subtle/difficult. It is actually sometimes easier to interpret the related pair correlation function, but this is harder to estimate. I highly recommend you read a bit more on the subject. Chapter 7 of [the spatstat book](http://book.spatstat.org/) is available as a free sample chapter and contains a lot of details on this (**disclaimer**: I'm a co-author of the book).

Comment: Cool! Thanks for your information. I'll read it now.