# Distribution of Difference between Functions

Tags: distributions

I am attempting to find the distribution of the difference between two functions.

In the images below I have one function in green, and one function in black defined by the red points.

When I calculate the RMS error between the green line and red points in the first image, I get a different answer than when I calculate the RMS error between the green line and red points in the second image.

What I really want is to know the RMS error between the green line and the black line, without having to calculate red millions of red points, or better yet, an approximate PDF of the distribution of the differences between the green and black lines.

I think a true distribution of the difference would be a sum of uniform random variables with bounds equal to the difference between the green line and red points in the first image, but I can't find any analytical or approximate distribution for that operation.

Does anyone have any suggestions on finding the distribution of the difference between the green and black functions, so I can find the mean and standard deviation of that distribution?

[image: fig1]
[image: fig2]

Comment: Because your black curve is piecewise linear and the green stepwise you can extrapolate the RMS between any 2 dots and then find a distribution without drawing 1000s of points. However I am not sure that this is easier to implement or faster to compute.

Comment: @Romain That approach is too much work.  The difference is a *mixture* of uniform distributions (not a sum as suggested in the question) and the number of distributions involved is at most the total number of $x$ values for the vertices appearing among the two functions.  Computing moments, like the mean square, takes effort only directly proportional to those vertex counts.

Answer (score 1):

#### About piecewise linear functions

You are given two *piecewise linear* functions.  A function $f$ is piecewise linear when it is "locally linear."  That is, for every $x$ in its domain there is an interval $I\ni x$ and constants $\alpha_I,$ $\beta_I$ for which

$$f_{\mid I}(x) = \alpha_I + \beta_I x.$$

Your representation of these functions appears to be in terms of their graphs, which are unions of line segments that, if they intersect at all, intersect only at endpoints.  For instance, the function $f$ with the black graph is the union of eight such segments connecting the nine red endpoints.  The function $g$ with the green graph also is the union of four segments.  (Notice that a piecewise linear function needn't be continuous!)  Let's call the $x$ values of the segments defining $f$ its "breaks."

The union of the breaks for $f$ and the breaks for $g$ determines the *only* points at which $f$ or $g$ may have "kinks" or "breaks."  As a first step, we may insert points into their graphs (wherever needed) so that $f$ and $g$ share the same set of breaks.  If $f$ and $g$ are not defined on the same domain, at this juncture we will also want to restrict them to the intersection of their domains, for otherwise it will make no sense to subtract them and carry out further calculations of that sort.

This figure shows functions like those in the question.  (I have modified them slightly in order to illustrate what happens when $f$ (black graph) and $g$ (green graph) do not originally have the same breaks.)  The values of these functions at their breaks are highlighted (as in the question) with point symbols.

[image: Figure 1]

The tan graph plots the difference $h = f-g.$  Notice that its breaks are the union of the breaks of $f$ and $g.$

#### Integrating piecewise linear functions

We have achieved a representation of $h$ as a collection of linear functions defined on a set of intervals. This makes it easy to integrate its square:

$$\begin{aligned}
\int h^2(x)\,\mathrm{d}x 
&= \sum_I \int_I h_{\mid I}^2(x)\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&= \sum_I \int_I (\alpha_I + \beta_I x)^2\,\mathrm{d}x \\
&= \sum_I \left(\alpha_I^2 x + \alpha_I\beta_I x^2 + \frac{1}{3}\beta_I^2 x^3\right)\mid_I
\end{aligned}\tag{*}$$

where, as usual, expressions of the form "$u(x)\mid_I$" mean to evaluate $u$ at the endpoints of $I$ and subtract.  Thus,

> The integral of $h^2 = (f-g)^2$ can be computed with $O(n)$ effort where $n$ is the total number of breakpoints occurring in $f$ and $g.$

The "mean squared error" is just this integral divided by the total lengths of the intervals involved.  Take the square root of that to obtain the root mean squared error.

Here is an example of the graph of $h^2$ from the previous figure.  Its mean value (that is, the mean squared difference between the original $f$ and $g$) is the height splitting the shaded region into two equal areas for the points above the mean and the points below the mean.

[image: Figure 2]

#### The distribution determined by a piecewise linear function

When $X$ is a random variable uniformly distributed on the domain of $h,$ we may conceive of $X$ as being a *mixture* of uniform distributions on the segments of $h.$ The mixture weights are, of course, just the relative lengths of the segments.

The distribution of $Y = h(X)$ also is a mixture of uniform distributions.  That is because on each interval, $Y$ is a linear transformation of $X$ and linear transformations of uniform distributions are uniform distributions.  Consequently, we may use techniques for working with mixture distributions to compute with $Y.$  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/122816/919 for a code sample to compute a general mixture density (which applies directly to computing the mixture PDF), https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/411671/919 for computing its quantile function, and https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/64058/919 for drawing values randomly from a mixture.

The next figure plots the distribution determined by the preceding $h$ using these techniques.

[image: Figure 3]

#### Comparing the calculations

We now have an abundance of methods available to compute the mean squared error.  They include

1. The direct calculation $(*).$
2. Black-box numerical integration of $(f-g)^2.$
3. Using the density $f_{h(X)},$ where the mean squared error is just the second (raw) moment.  It can be computed in various ways, such as by black-box numerical integration of $y^2 f_{h(X)}(y)\,\mathrm{d}y.$

When I carried out these calculations for the running example, the output was

```
   Direct Numerical   Density 
5.9961458 5.9961469 5.9961458
```

You can see differences in the seventh decimal place, well within the error estimated by the black-box integrator (the `integrate` function in `R`).  Some error in the block-box integrator is to be expected, because its doesn't know that what it is integrating has a piecewise definition, forcing it to estimate where any jumps or spikes might be and creating (smallish) errors where it interpolates across them.